# Помогите решить проблему Unity

Tags: unity3d

Есть лист где хранятся объекты.
1 класс

```
public  List<GameObject> heroInventoryCard = new List<GameObject>();
```

Во 2 классе идет поиск объекта где находится скрипт с листом и создание объектов на экране.

```
 GameObject findHero = GameObject.Find("ork berserk prefab");
         List <GameObject> displeyHeInvent = findHero.GetComponent<HeInventoryContr>().heroInventoryCard;

       for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++) // лимит карт
        {
          int x = -1;
            x = x + (i * 2);
           Instantiate(displeyHeInvent[i], new Vector3(x, 15, -7), displeyHeInvent[i].transform.rotation);

        }
```

Задача. Как сделать чтобы созданные объекты по клику удалялись из листа который находиться в 1 классе

Comment: лист это ссылочный тип.  Ссылку вы скопировали. Значит можете изменять. Теперь вы можете изменять displeyHeInvent и изменения затронут heroInventoryCard

Comment: Спасибо за инфу. Я забыл добавить, что мне надо удалить не весь массив, а именно индекс по которому кликнули. То есть, если кликнули 1 карту удалить из массива индекс 0 по 2 индекс 1. Я кажется придумал, но может вы подкинете интересную идею.

Comment: вы можете использовать метод листа Remove(item). Если есть совпадение то он удалит этот элемент из списка.  Это то что вам нужно. если я все правильно понял. А вместо item передаете gameObkect который получаете с клика